# How to get the selected item from a AutoCompleteTextView with a custom Adapter

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

So I have a custom Adapter which basically loads an icon and a text, resulting into the following view:

[image]

Now the probem is, that whenever I select one of these items, two problems occur:

1. The icon does not show inside of the autoCompleteTextView.
2. The text shows inside, but I'm unable to change it again...if I click that little arrow to open the list again, it just doesn't open.

I only get that behavior when I add the following code:

```
      exchangeBinding.autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
        val item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
        if (item is PaymentMethod) {
            exchangeBinding.autoCompleteTextView.setText(item.paymentMethodName)
            exchangeBinding.autoCompleteTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(item.paymentMethodIcon, 0, 0,0)
        
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the problem for both issues.

Apparently, the filter is set to true by default on "setText", so it should be set to false instead and that's why the list was not showing any items the second time:

```
 exchangeBinding.autoCompleteTextView.setText(item.paymentMethodName, false)
```

As for the icon I had to set it for the TextInputLayout instead of the autoComplete.

```
exchangeBinding.textInputLayoutDropDown.startIconDrawable = drawable
```